# GPO to clear the browser caches/data when closing browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, browser-cache, gpo

I need to create a GPO in order to clear the browser caches/data when closing browsers.  I will need to apply this to IE, Edge, and Chrome browsers.

But checking it's no way to clear all cache in a GPO, Could you please help me?

Investigate on Internet

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there're existing policies to clear browsing data on close for each browser. Check them if they're what you want. You need to configure three policies:

**IE**

Path: `Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Delete Browsing History/Allow deleting browsing history on exit`

You can simply enable this policy. Reference: https://admx.help/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::DBHDisableDeleteOnExit

**Edge**

Path: `Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/Clear browsing data when Microsoft Edge closes`

You can simply enable this policy. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#clearbrowsingdataonexit

**Chrome**

Path: `Administrative Templates/Classic Administrative Templates/Google/Google Chrome/Clear Browsing Data on Exit`

You need to provide a list of strings. Reference: https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ClearBrowsingDataOnExitList